# Ошибка при сборке проекта под android с помощью buildozer

Tags: python, kivy

Во время сборки вылетает ошибка:

```
[ERROR]:   Build failed: python-for-android no longer supports running under Python 2. Either upgrade to Python 3.4 or higher (recommended), or revert to python-for-android 2019.07.08. Note that you *can* still target Python 2 on Android by including python2 in your requirements.
```

Описание:

```
Command failed: /usr/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python2,python3,kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/home/grosterra/Рабочий стол/test/.buildozer/android/platform/build" --ndk-api=21
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     USER = 'grosterra'
#     DBUS_STARTER_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus,guid=4d46e3c53f75c7c337ed89ec5d622c79'
#     GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID = 'this-is-deprecated'
#     XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu:GNOME'
#     XDG_SESSION_TYPE = 'x11'
#     QT_IM_MODULE = 'xim'
#     LOGNAME = 'grosterra'
#     XDG_SEAT = 'seat0'
#     PATH = '/home/grosterra/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/grosterra/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin'
#     XDG_VTNR = '2'
#     HOME = '/home/grosterra'
#     DISPLAY = ':0'
#     SSH_AGENT_PID = '2058'
#     XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu'
#     MANAGERPID = '1921'
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
#     XAUTHORITY = '/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority'
#     LANGUAGE = 'ru_UA:ru'
#     SESSION_MANAGER = 'local/UBUNTU-VB:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1957,unix/UBUNTU-VB:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1957'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/home/grosterra/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     CLUTTER_IM_MODULE = 'xim'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     QT4_IM_MODULE = 'xim'
#     QT_ACCESSIBILITY = '1'
#     WINDOWPATH = '2'
#     XMODIFIERS = '@im=ibus'
#     GPG_AGENT_INFO = '/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1'
#     XDG_SESSION_CLASS = 'user'
#     INVOCATION_ID = '00b4ee7c5c9a41a38606ccba4623288d'
#     USERNAME = 'grosterra'
#     LANG = 'ru_UA.UTF-8'
#     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/1000'
#     SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh'
#     VTE_VERSION = '5602'
#     JOURNAL_STREAM = '9:31062'
#     GDMSESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     IM_CONFIG_PHASE = '2'
#     GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE = 'ubuntu'
#     DBUS_STARTER_BUS_TYPE = 'session'
#     LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
#     XDG_SESSION_ID = '3'
#     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus,guid=4d46e3c53f75c7c337ed89ec5d622c79'
#     _ = '/usr/local/bin/buildozer'
#     GNOME_TERMINAL_SERVICE = ':1.88'
#     GTK_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     DESKTOP_SESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/home/grosterra/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     XDG_CONFIG_DIRS = '/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg'
#     GTK_MODULES = 'gail:atk-bridge'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/home/grosterra/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r17c'
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
#     PWD = '/home/grosterra/\xd0\xa0\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb1\xd0\xbe\xd1\x87\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb9 \xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbb/test'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '27'
#     COLORTERM = 'truecolor'
#     XDG_MENU_PREFIX = 'gnome-'
#     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
#     GNOME_TERMINAL_SCREEN = '/org/gnome/Terminal/screen/e21ab30b_7b88_4ece_9ae9_25b9b269341e'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Может кто-то сталкивался. Подскажите как можно решить пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно в виртуальном окружении установить Python3, затем повторно установить buildozer и заново собрать проект.

Answer (score 0):

`python3 -m buildozer android debug` -- попробуй этот вариант.